# Angular JS with REST server: Use and set temporary data(cookie or others)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, cookies

Hi I'm integrating a REST server with my Angular JS front-end project.

The thing is, when I use some traditional, integrated web-framework, they could help me to set cookie. For example, if I want to log in a user, I could store it's user ID in session and put a token inside the cookie.

But now my front-end and back-end are separated, the front-end client will get a token from back-end server to prove he is logged in and authorized. How could I remember this in Angular JS? Could I simply use the $cookie built-in variable? And what about it's life-cycle in Angular JS? Is this safe?

And is there another way to store some temporary value in Angular JS? Actually my communication with the server is only served by JSON, I don't need cookie at all if there's another way to store temporary information. **But**, if I just save it in the `$scope`, is it safe? Especially for some secret tokens...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should use the `$cookie` to store the session but if you need just a quick and dirty way to test something out use `$rootScope` to store it temporarily but never use this in production.

Comment: @JoeLloyd Thanks for your comment. Could I ask why it's necessary to use `$cookie`, for its security or something else?

Comment: `$rootScope` is a global variable and should be avoided. cookie was built to store the kind of information you want to store so make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some modules like:

- https://github.com/sahat/satellizer
- https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth

Comment: wael, I really appreciate your help, I think these repos are really really good! :) But which one do you prefer, and more easy to use?

Comment: depends on your use case